# Sending parameters in multipart/form-data using Android 7 and Node.js

Tags: javascript, android, node.js

I've been searching everywhere for a way to do a post request using Node.js as my back-end and android as my front-end. After asking many people we discovered that my body-parser in express Node.js had problems. I tried to fix the problem by reinstalling the parser and thus making sure no file was missing, but it still doesn't work. Therefore, my Node.js post method only receives `multipart/form-data`.

I can't seem to find anywhere for a way to send parameters in `multipart/form-data` using `HttpUrlConnection` and `Asynctask` since **in the newer versions of android** `OkHttpClient` and `HttpPost` aren't supported.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Use Volley or OkHttp or Retrofit for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) for making Api Calls in Android.

It is a simplified Library which gives functionalities like sending Mutipart Form Data, providing headers, convert JSON to class object using inbuilt converters etc.